# Is the intersection of an infinite closed sets is closed

Tags: general-topology

I think it's not necessarily has to be closed but I'm not sure if I have a counter example.

Let $V_k\in \mathbb R$ a closed set where $V_k=(-\infty ,1+\frac1 k]$, now I'm not sure what the intersection will result in?

$\bigcap_1^\infty  V_k=(-\infty,1]$?

I feel like its not 1 but I cant put my finger on what will it result mabye $1+\varepsilon$.

Comment: Arbitrary unions of open sets be open is equivalent to say that arbitrary unions of closed sets are closed. So the answer is yes and the reason is just an axiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your intuition suggests, we have
$$
\bigcap_{k \geq 1} V_k = (-\infty, 1]
$$
which is indeed closed. Indeed, first note that the inclusion $(-\infty,1] \subseteq \bigcap_{k \geq 1} V_k$ is trivial. Conversely, if $x \in \bigcap_{k \geq 1} V_k$, then we have 
$$
-\infty < x \leq 1 + \frac{1}{k}
$$
for **all** $k \geq 1$. Therefore we must have $x \leq 1$ (try to convince yourself of this!) so that $x \in (-\infty,1]$.

More generally, **any** intersection of closed sets must be closed. To see this, let $\{F_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ be any (possibly uncountable) family of closed sets. By definition, each $F_\alpha^\complement$ will be open. Consequently,
\begin{align*}
\left( \bigcap_{\alpha \in I} F_\alpha\right)^\complement = \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} F_\alpha^\complement
\end{align*}
is open (arbitrary unions of open sets are open!) as well. It follows that $\bigcap_{\alpha \in I} F_\alpha$ is closed.

Comment: Yes I had a typo, and thank you for the great proof (looks so easy after all... feels kinda bad).

Comment: @MercyDude Don't worry about that; it's all part of the learning process!